# Problems with the title and the margin in LyX

Tags: lyx, margins, titles

I have prepared my document and when I created the PDF I realized the problem I got with one title and the right margin. This is out of the margin.

How can I fix this?

(I am new with LyX)

Comment: you can probably force a break before Projects with `\\Projects` or wherever you want it to break the line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perfect man!! easy and simple Thanks a lot!!

Comment: with one of the edits, the example was removed.  without the example, the question makes little sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a forced line break in a section title by placing the cursor where you want the break to occur and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Such breaks are indicated in the GUI with an arrow going down, then left (as on a enter key). This is basically the same as writing `\\` in an ERT.

In other cases where you have long words sticking into the margin and TeX is unable to hyphenate it, an option is to help TeX a little by adding specific hyphenation points. In LyX you do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, or Insert --> Formatting --> Hyphenation point. For this specific case a line break may be better, but in normal text, adding hyphenation points would be better.

[image]